# ESXi management freezes

Tags: virtualization, vmware, esxi

I've been running an environment at home running ESXi 6.7 for some of my school projects and to learn more about virtualization.

Currently, there is a Plex VM and a webserver VM. The host specs are:

i7-2600K

48 GB Memory

15 HDDs

Almost every other time I log into the ESXi management interface or through vCenter, the management interface freezes and I can no longer connect to it. The VMs stay up and running just fine though. I have noticed that sometimes right before it happens, the CPU maxes out. I get no purple screen or any other sign that something is wrong.

I honestly can't figure out exactly whats broken. I had this issue on 6.5 as well, and upgrading to 6.7 didn't solve anything. The logs don't say much of anything either.

Should I just blow the entire host away and start from scratch? Would running a memtest be a good thing to try?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I assume your using the VSphere web client?  I also assume VCenter is running within a VM on the ESXi host.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: These 15 HDDs are all configured NOT to power down when not in use?